# Is it possible to force autoplay multiple HTML5 videos on the same page?

Tags: html, html5-video

Normally, if you have two or more HTML5 videos with autoplay set to true, none of them will play automatically. This is so that you don't get a bunch of soundtracks blaring at the same time.

However, if you just use some small, mute looping videos as backgrounds or otherwise decorative elements, this limitation is useless.

Is there a way to force them to play automatically? I really don't want to resort to GIFs. Thank you.

Comment: Tried using something similar to `document.getElementById('myVideo').play();`, that runs after the video element has been loaded?

Comment: @AlgernopK. Yes, I tried, but it doesn't work. Neither of the videos are playing. There's an error in the console.

Comment: @AlgernopK. The error is as follows: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.`

Comment: Might be suggesting that you're trying to play them before they're all loaded. Try adding a small delay using `setTimeout(function () { });` before playing them, alt. finding a way of knowing when the videos are loaded and then playing them.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the exact same problem inside a WordPress post